# How do you block or permanently delete Outlook emails with the red badge (icon)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I get an internal security error when trying to block or permanently delete these emails with the red badge (icon).

Comment: Screenshot? Text of the error, please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this icon?

[image]

This icon means the email has a valid digital Signature. ([What do the Outlook icons mean?)](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/icons.htm)

For Encrypted emails, try Shift+Delete and choose Yes.

Some ways are also mentioned in these similar threads:

[Unable to delete email: "Your digital ID name cannot be found by the underlying security system"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1145b4be-fc7e-41b7-80c3-f9b69f381cfa/unable-to-delete-email-quotyour-digital-id-name-cannot-be-found-by-the-underlying-security?forum=outlook)

[Can't permanently delete an encrypted e-mail...](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14892ba0-b896-4314-9ad8-4d040d7cd496/cant-permanently-delete-an-encrypted-email?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy)

Since you no longer have the certification to operate the encrypted message, the workaround is to drag these emails to a new PST file and then delete that PST file.